# hourlyVirtualGuests Upgrade/Downgrade Responses Dropped

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm invoking an upgrade of vCPU and memory to a collection of hourlyVirtualGuest hosts.  I am finding that, depending on how many I do at a time, some requests fail to complete without generating an error.

My current logic is to post 10 upgrade/downgrade operations and then sleep for a period of time.  If I sleep for 60 seconds in the loop, then everything completes fine.  If I drop the sleep to 30 seconds, all requests are accepted but several do not complete.  I can play with sleep values, but the fact that a subset of these requests are dropped without an alert is a concern.  Am I overflowing a queue somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is strange, you could try to bulk all your upgrade requests in a single order and see what happens.

The container for the placeOrder method has a property called "orderContainers" where you can set up a list of upgrade orders.

take a look to this example using the Softlayer Python client, I am adding to upgrade resquests in the same order:

```
"""
Upgrade  VSIs.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder/


License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

virtualGuestId = 26252013
virtualGuestId2 = 26252013

# Setting the configuration for a upgrade a VM
orderContainer = {}
orderContainer['packageId'] = 46
orderContainer['complexType'] = 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade'
orderContainer['virtualGuests'] = [{'id': virtualGuestId}]
orderContainer['prices'] = [
    # Upgraqdes prices
    { 'id': 1644 }
]
orderContainer['properties'] = [{'name': 'MAINTENANCE_WINDOW', 'value': 'now'}]

# Setting the configuration for a upgrade another VM
orderContainer2 = {}
orderContainer2['packageId'] = 46
orderContainer2['complexType'] = 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade'
orderContainer2['virtualGuests'] = [{'id': virtualGuestId2}]
orderContainer2['prices'] = [
    # Upgraqdes prices
    { 'id': 1644 }
]
orderContainer2['properties'] = [{'name': 'MAINTENANCE_WINDOW', 'value': 'now'}]

#adding the upgrade orders to the container
orderData = {
    "orderContainers": [
        orderContainer,
        orderContainer2
    ],
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order'
}

print (orderData)

orderClient = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    result = orderClient['Product_Order'].verifyOrder(orderData)
    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to upgrade the VSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Regards

Comment: That's interesting.  I'm trying to play with this idea now to see how many upgrade requests I can put through in a given order without the API objecting.  Any idea what kind of limiting would be in place?  I'm assuming I can't do 50 upgrades in one go.

Comment: As an additional question, the "prices" attribute is problematic.  Is there a way to enumerate this value for a given item in a given DC?  It seems like this number changes depending on which DC you're in, so there's potentially a lot of options.

Comment: I do not know, I've never ordered that amount in one order, documentation does not say anythin about limits, so you should be able to order 50 or more upgrades at once.

Comment: regarding the prices yes there is a way you need to use object filters, see this article http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you if you need help with the objectfilter do not hestite to ask :).